Calculate surface area of a geography instance using StArea() in T-SQL
In my (Azure SQL Server) database I have stored polygons in the format "MULTIPOLYGON (((longitude1 latitude1, longitude2 latitude2, etc)))".
I want to calculate the total surface area of these polygons using the STArea() function. When using the following code, I get an extremely large surface area which is not correct.
DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((longitude1 latitude1, longitude2 latitude2, etc)))', 4326); 
SELECT @g.STArea();

When I (manually) change the order of longitude and latitude I do get a surface area that seems correct but changing the order does not make any sense to me and does not align with the geographic instances. Also, I do not see an option how I can change the order of the coordinates for an entire table of polygons.
Can someone explain me what is going wrong and how to correctly use the STArea() function?
BTW. I am using DBeaver to do my calculations.

Sometimes a wrong winding order of a polygon ring can make a software think that the area is the whole world outside the polygon. Your code looks similar to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-ver16 so I think that longitude-latitude in the WKT is ok.
